# Excel 2007 VBA issue with structured references

Tags: excel, vba

If I create a range from a structured reference and do try to run a find function, Excel throws a `50290 Error Application-defined or object-defined error`. From what Google says, the error seems to be related to a missing reference. What that missing reference is is not obvious from looking through Tools/References.

```
 Set colRange = Range("TABLE[COLUMN]")
 Set r = colRange.Find(id, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Line 2 throws the error. The colRange variable looks just fine in the watch window. I can extract values from it using `.Cells` property. `Find (Ctrl+F)` works fine. I hope I am not overlooking something simple.

Comment: Where do you write your code? `Module` or `ActiveX Control`? I wrote mine in a `Module` and it works. The same cannot be said if you wrote it in an `ActiveX Control` since it will force you to put the `Control` in the same sheet where you have your structured data.

Answer (score 0):

If its not able to find id in colrange then reference to object r is not defined.
and when u use any property of object r, it will throw error.

hope this answer your query, if not paste ur code here, will check that.